# Docker container not able to access port 5432

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a spring application which is trying to connect postgres db (jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxx:5432/My_DB). It connects fine when I run the jar using "java -jar app.jar" command.But when i run inside the docker container it fails to connect. Below is the command , I used to run.

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 my_image:latest
```

It looks like 5432 is not open inside the container seems. I came across a similar post for this, but didnt give any solutions.
[Docker container for Postgres 9.1 not exposing port 5432 to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928670/docker-container-for-postgres-9-1-not-exposing-port-5432-to-host)

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to specifically user `Expose 5432` in your docker file. Otherwise it is not allowed to expose it via a container.